# How to get innerHTML of a body before its loading is completed?

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML body, and I want to get its full inner HTML code **before** its loading is completed.

```
<body someproperties>
     <!--- some elements --->
     <script>
         var html = getFullInnerHTMLsomeWay();
     </script>
     <!--- some elements --->
</body>
```

So, the question is, how can I get its full inner HTML code before all its child are loaded?
I have tried many ideas but no success yet.
I also tried to google it but didn't find anything helpful.

**Edit:** My goal is to replace all instances of a specified text to another text before they displayed to the user.

Comment: What a strange question? Could you explain why you need this? And show some code you've already try. You have the `window.onload` event. But all the contains will already loaded. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: The counter-question to this is obviously: "why?". What are you trying to do that made you think that the way to do that is look at the DOM in HTML form before the DOM has finished parsing?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I want to replace all instances of some text to another text before it becomes shown.

Comment: @איתןרבינוביץ A MutationObserver will work, then.

Comment: in that case you should be able to just load your script from file, with the [defer attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer), whose sole reason for existing is to cause your script to run after the DOM has been parsed, but _before_ DOMContentLoaded is triggered, so you can do exactly what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The first time elements become interactable with (and, for example, viewable from the DOM APIs and by the user) is when the browser inserts them into the DOM.

Given

```
<body someproperties>
     <!--- some elements 1 --->
     <script>
         console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
     </script>
     <!--- some elements 2 --->
</body>
```

you will get the contents of `some elements 1`, as well as the script tag, but there's no way to get `some elements 2` because it hasn't been loaded yet.

You will only be able to get `some elements 2` after the `<script>` tag finishes executing.

The only way I can think of to do something *like* this would be to [completely stop the page from loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop), `fetch` the current page, then parse the response, and then finally load the response into the current page - which would be quite convoluted, and I wouldn't recommend it at all.

It's not exactly what you were asking, but if desirable, you can alter or view the HTML before it gets displayed - use a MutationObserver to watch for appended nodes on the `body`.

```
new MutationObserver(() => {
  // examine DOM here
  // can add and remove nodes as needed, before they get rendered
})
  .observe(document.body, { childList: true });
```